# Laravel Lumen Php Artisan : Make Model User ERROR Command "make:model" is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I tried to run the command below in the terminal, and it generates an error as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nt46.png)

thank you for your help :)

I've tried composer require wn/lumen-generators but the results are as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkXOG.jpg)